# Open Files difference between host and container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, docker, ulimit

I have a Golang application that receives a high volume of traffic and should keep a low latency SLA. Recently we are investigating if the fact that we are running the application in a Docker container is somehow degrading the application performance. So we are trying to compare it by running it directly on the host machine (EC2).
We are facing an issue that the host is reaching the '`Too Many Open Files`' error very fast.

Few facts:

1. The container runs without a `ulimit` (using the hosts ulimits).
2. When I do `lsof` and summing all the lines - I am not reaching the limit (1048576).

Comment: You aren't getting any response on this. Can you spend a bit more time, improving the question. Is there anything else that may be relevant, that you can tell us?